# Is it safe to detach and reattach this propane hose with a household wrench?

Tags: tools, fireplace, propane

I'm wondering if it would be safe to use a household wrench to detach (and reattach) this propane hose at the coupling indicated by the yellow arrow if I've shut off the gas supply at the propane tank and at the red shutoff valve in the picture.

[image: propane_hose]

I've already shut off the main propane tank that this pipe is attached to.

It's my assumption that once I shut off the red valve on the hose as well, I can use a wrench to unscrew the coupling on the hose, which is attached to a gas log fireplace insert.

But I wanted to ask the community since I didn't know if I'd need a special tool, or to take other precautions.

Comment: You want two well fitting wrenches, one to hold the smaller nut in place and one to turn the nut with the yellow arrow.

Comment: what is a `household wrench`?

Comment: Do NOT use pipe dope on a flare connection. ( I am not certain which connection you will open.)

Comment: Does **not appear to apply** here, as best I can see in a tiny picture, but beware of fuel gas fittings that have a slot cur around the hex flats. Those ones are lefty-tighty, rightly loosey.

Comment: @Ecnerwal   Wish all lefties had that.  Would save quite a bit of time when trying to loosen a nut.

Answer (score 3):

That is about the only way do disconnect it. Be sure to use a second wrench to back it up when unscrewing. I know of no special wrench to do this, it looks like standard fittings. If it is to be left off purchase a cap and place it on it to prevent leaks if some valves are inadvertently turned on.

When you reassemble it be sure to use two wrenches. Be sure to check for leaks. There electronic detectors to do this or my favorite bubble soap.

Comment: If you do _not_ hold the smaller nut on the valve, you may end up twisting the whole assembly, crimping and potentially cracking open the non-flexible copper tubing above the valve.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out you need two wrenches to hold the valve body and to unscrew the nut.

For additional protection ground the wrenches with pice of wire  so not to create a spark.